# Incompatible cv qualifiers in parent class method

Tags: c++, class, gtk, gtkmm, glade

I'm tinkering with C++ and gtkmm, trying to create a custom class that calls upon a .glade file to build a Gtk rather basic interface. This class is derived from `Gtk::Window`, however when I call the `get_widget` method on the class itself, I get the error:

```
types ‘const T_Widget*’ and ‘myClass* const’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers
```

Class definition:

```
class myClass: public Gtk::Window{

    public:
    myClass(); 

    protected:
    //...
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;
    //...

}
```

However I am trying to upload data from the glade file into my class (on the class constructor):

```
//...
builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("../glade/myClass.glade");
builder->get_widget("window1",this);
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

`myClass* const` is not the same as `const myClass*`.
In the first one the pointer is constant, and in the second one the object is.
Just declare it like :  `const myClass*`

But your problem seems unrelated (my bad), GTK has a special function for derived class :
[Gtk::Builder::get_widget_derived](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Builder.html#aa3fec8b2dc543cf85495e619b3dfd9fd), 
use this instead.

Comment: where exactly would I do that?

Comment: I'm getting the error  `error: no matching function for call to ‘Gtk::Builder::get_widget_derived(const char [8], myClass* const)’
   builder->get_widget_derived("window1",this);` after replacing `get_widget` with `get_widget_derived`

Comment: Can you show more code ? According to documentation, you're not supposed to do this in the constructor anyway : Gtk::DerivedBox* pBox = 0;
refXml->get_widget_derived("mybox", pBox); They create an object for you, so passing this will not work.

Comment: I'm using the example in the gtkmm book section about "timeouts" https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-timeouts.html.en, I'm trying to modify it to build the GUI from a glade file.

Comment: I did change the constructor, but ommited the gtkBuilder part because I already have a builder as a class member

Comment: you can load each part (buttons, boxes) from the glade file, but maybe not the class itself. If you want to this, you'll have to do a wrapper class that will have a pointer to your derived class.